# How to disable "USB Over Current Notification" popups in the Finder in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, usb, finder

On an Intel iMac (Model MB324LL/A) (currently running 10.6.4), every few minutes (or seconds) I get a Finder popup window reading:

> Because a USB device was drawing too much power from your computer, one or more of your USB devices have been disabled.

In Console, the associated message:

> USB Notificaton: The device "EHCI Root Hub Simulation" @ 0xfa000000 has caused an overcurrent condition. The hub it is attached to has been disabled.

What I want: a way to prevent these messages from showing up in the Finder. Any solution that prevents or reduces the annoyance would be most appreciated.

*For reference: this occurs with our without USB devices plugged in, with any boot disk I've tried. I've reset the SMC and the PRAM. I assume it's the motherboard, and I'm simply looking for the cheapest way to make this a usable paper-writing, web-browsing beast of burden.*

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this should be at superuser.com.  Or if the iMac is under warranty, call Apple.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a great solution, but you can stop the messages with:

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserNotificationCenter.plist

They'll still appear in the system log (because the hardware fault is still there), but it stops the dialog pop up messages.

Comment: I got an error when I tried this verbatim, but found this variation instead:
    sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserNotificationCenter.plist

Comment: Sorry, looks like my copy-paste got truncated.  Adding .plist to the end is correct.

Comment: Yeah, this is a take-a-sledgehammer-to-a-window-to-kill-a-fly approach... as it disables _all_ notifications, right? (Even e.g. the actually-actionable ones, like Calendar event notifications).